# Cannot get Javascript to change the header according to y-position

Tags: javascript, html, css, debugging, scroll

I was working on this project where I am currently trying to give a shrinking effect to the header when the user scrolls down. I did my best to display the code, but it refuses to work. And since I am new to JavaScript, I am not able to effectively debug it. Please help
Here is the code:

```js
function smallHeaderSet() {
  var yPosition = window.pageYOffset,
    bigHeader = document.querySelector("header"),
    smallHeader = document.getElementById("headerSmall"),
    positionLimit = 150;
  if (yPosition > positionLimit) {
    smallHeader.style.display = "block";
    bigHeader.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Caviar, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #FFFF61;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
p,
#text_area,
span {
  z-index: 0;
  font-size: 1.1em;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
}
/* start the whole heading section */

header h1 {
  font-size: 5em;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Alex Brush", "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  padding-left: 2%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
#hOneSmall {
  font-size: 2.5em;
  color: #000000;
  font-family: "Alex Brush", "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  padding-left: 1.2%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 1%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav h2,
#smallNav h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
header nav {
  float: right;
  font-family: Junction, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-right: 2%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
#smallNav {
  float: right;
  font-family: Junction, "Times New Roman", sans-serif;
  font-size: .7em;
  padding-top: 1.2%;
  padding-right: 1.2%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}
header nav a,
#smallNav a {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
header nav a:hover,
#smallNav a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
header nav a:visited,
#smallNav a:visited {
  color: #000b26;
}
header {
  background-color: #ff5e5e;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  /*box-shadow: 5px 8px 30px #000000;*/
  height: 20vh;
}
#headerSmall {
  background-color: #ff5e5e;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 999;
  /*box-shadow: 5px 8px 30px #000000;*/
  height: 10vh;
}
#headerSmall {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--Student144 | Period 6 | Lab 6-->
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Stamp World.</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="font.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#checking").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#checking .checktext").fadeIn(450);
      });
      $("#checking").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#checking .checktext").fadeOut(200);
      });

      $("#checking2").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#checking2 .checktext").fadeIn(450);
      });
      $("#checking2").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#checking2 .checktext").fadeOut(200);
      });

      $("#checking3").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#checking3 .checktext").fadeIn(450);
      });
      $("#checking3").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#checking3 .checktext").fadeOut(200);
      });

      $("#checking4").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#checking4 .checktext").fadeIn(450);
      });
      $("#checking4").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#checking4 .checktext").fadeOut(200);
      });

      $("#checking5").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#checking5 .checktext").fadeIn(450);
      });
      $("#checking5").mouseleave(function() {
        $("#checking5 .checktext").fadeOut(200);
      });
    });
  </script>
  <script>
    var checkMore = "False"

    function toggleText() {
      var lessText = "Stamps might not be a big part in our modern day life, but it was one of the most important things for some one to communicate with another before e-mails or cell phones were introduced (or before they became common in everyday life). It was one of the most important ways through which the government got revenue and through which people were, in a way, express their feelings through different stamps. It was a big deal to get a stamp that was newly released or was declared to be only produced in few amount, so the race for stamp collection started way before it became extinct, and is still going on.";
      var moreText = " It started as a sportive thing to do, like as a hobby, but over the course of two-three decades, those ancient stamps were worth a lot because of their rareness. Of course one can simply replicate the stamps and sell them for low cost (some even cheat by selling them as the real ones!), but business people see these trades seriously; they have teams that study those stamps, who verify the validity of the specific stamp, before buying it. Why? Well their cost would eventually increase over time, which is a profit for the buyer, and it is also a way to showcase their wealth."
      if (checkMore == "False") {
        document.getElementById("text_area").innerText = lessText + moreText;
        document.getElementById("toggler").innerText = "Show Less";
        checkMore = "True";
      } else if (checkMore == "True") {
        document.getElementById("text_area").innerText = lessText;
        document.getElementById("toggler").innerText = "Show More";
        checkMore = "False";
      }
    }

    function smallHeaderSet() {
      var yPosition = window.pageYOffset,
        bigHeader = document.querySelector("header"),
        smallHeader = document.getElementById("headerSmall"),
        positionLimit = 150;
      if (yPosition > positionLimit) {
        smallHeader.style.display = "block";
        bigHeader.style.display = "none";
      }
    }

    var position, backgroundEffect, backgroundEffect2, backgroundEffect3;

    function parallax() {
      backgroundEffect = document.getElementById('background_two');
      backgroundEffect2 = document.getElementById('background_three');
      backgroundEffect3 = document.getElementById('background_four');
      position = window.pageYOffset;
      backgroundEffect.style.top = position * -0.15 + 'px';
      backgroundEffect2.style.top = position * -0.4 + 'px';
      backgroundEffect3.style.top = position * -0.155 + 'px';
    }
    window.addEventListener('scroll', parallax), false;
  </script>
  <style>
    #toggler {
      text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #toggler:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <!--open main div-->

    <header>
      <h1>Stamp World.</h1>
      <nav>
        <h2>
<a href = "index.htm">Home</a>
</h2>
      </nav>
    </header>
    <!--close header-->

    <div id="headerSmall">
      <div id="hOneSmall">Stamp World.</div>
      <div id="smallNav">
        <h2>
<a href = "index.htm">Home</a>
</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--header small-->
</body>

</html>
```

Basically I want the small header section to appear and the big header to fade away/disappear when the user scrolls down, and the vice-versa when the use scrolls up.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Where is `smallHeaderSet()` called? I only see the function definition and no calls to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have defined function smallHeaderSet() but never call it. You need to create an event listener for a scroll event to call this function when the user scrolls.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
    smallHeaderSet();
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I just have one quick question, what does function(e) mean and what does it do?

Comment: function (e) is called an anonymous function. Its not named, it can't be manually called with someFunctionName() and e is its parameter which is the event object, in this case the scroll event.

Comment: That's interesting. Thank you so much!